# How to get common values of multiple nested array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, algorithm, data-structures, javascript-objects

i want to get common values by name not by id, from every view. for eg: here 'view 6' and 'view 2'  is common.

-here is my response (allDeviceView):

```
[
    {
        "ip": "111.11.11.11",
        "views": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "View 2",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "View 3",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "View 4",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "View 5",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "View 6",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ip": "222.22.22.22",
        "views": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "View 1",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "View 2",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "View 6",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ip": "144.44.44.44",
        "views": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "View 2",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "View 6",
                "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

-i want to get the common objects from views by name not by id, so here 'view 6' and 'view 2' is common.
currently i am getting values only if they are occurring more than one time, but there can be multiple objects so i have to get common in each of views.

-expected output:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "View 2",
    "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "View 6",
    "thumbnail": "http://media.fanconnect.tv/production/app/635_879656_thumbnail.jpg"
}
```

-i tried doing it by :

```
 const deviceViewsMaps = allDeviceView?.map((d: any) => d.views).flat();
const flattened = [...deviceViewsMaps];

    /*eslint-disable */
    const counts = flattened.reduce(
      (map, { name }) => map.set(name, (map.get(name) || 0) + 1),
      new Map(),
    );

    /*eslint-enable */
    const names: any = [];

    const found = flattened.filter(({ name }) => {
      if (counts.get(name) > 1 && !names.includes(name)) {
        names.push(name);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });

    console.log(found, 'data');

    setFilteredDeviceView(found);
```

Comment: *" here view3 and view7 are common"*: I see "View 3" only once, and there's no "View 7" in your data. Can you explain what you mean with "common"?

Comment: What is the expected output for the input you have provided?

Comment: yes, sorry, just edited now , only 'view 6' is common here among all views

Comment: Why is "View 2" not in the expected output?

Comment: yes, 'view 2' and 'view 6' are common

Comment: And that is what your current script is outputing. I don't understand what the problem is you are asking about.

Comment: my current code is outputting 'view 1', 'view 2', and 'view 6' , but i only want 'view 2' and 'view 6' , which will be common among all views array

Comment: I ran your code and it is not outputting that. It outputs an array with two objects, the one for "View 2" and for "View 6". I don't see what you are asking here. See [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8pL6fwn5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const deviceViewsMaps = allDeviceView?.map((d: any) => d.views || '[]').flat();

const deviceNameMap = allDeviceView?.map((d: any) => d.ip);

const flattened = [...deviceViewsMaps];

/*eslint-disable */
const counts = flattened.reduce(
  (map, { name }) => map.set(name, (map.get(name) || 0) + 1),
  new Map(),
);

/*eslint-enable */
const names: any = [];

const found = flattened.filter(({ name }) => {
//---------------------
      //here i have increased count with number of ip length. i.e : deviceNameMap.length - 1
//---------------------
  if (counts.get(name) > deviceNameMap.length - 1 && !names.includes(name)) {
    names.push(name);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

setFilteredDeviceView(found);
```